# PHP regex replace multiple patterns with callback

Tags: php, regex, pcre, preg-replace-callback

I'm trying to run a simple replacement on some input data that could be described as follows:

- take a regular expression
- take an input data stream
- on every match, replace the match through a callback

Unfortunately, preg_replace_callback() doesn't work as I'd expect. It gives me all the matches on the entire line, not individual matches. So I need to put the line together again after replacement, but I don't have the information to do that. Case in point:

```
<?php
echo replace("/^\d+,(.*),(.*),.*$/", "12,LOWERME,ANDME,ButNotMe")."\n";
echo replace("/^\d+-\d+-(.*) .* (.*)$/", "13-007-THISLOWER ThisNot THISAGAIN")."\n";


function replace($pattern, $data) {
    return preg_replace_callback(
        $pattern, 
        function($match) {
            return strtolower($match[0]);
        }, $data
    );
}
```

https://www.tehplayground.com/hE1ZBuJNtFiHbdHO

gives me `12,lowerme,andme,butnotme`, but I want `12,lowerme,andme,ButNotMe`.

I know using $match[0] is wrong. It's just to illustrate here. Inside the closure I need to run something like

```
foreach ($match as $m) { /* do something */ }
```

But as I said, I have no information about the position of the matches in the input string which makes it impossible to put the string together again.

I've digged through the PHP documentation as well as several searches and couldn't find a solution.

---

Clarifications:

I know that $match[1], $match[2]... etc contain the matches. But only a string, not a position. Imagine in my example the final string is also ANDME instead of ButNotMe - according to the regex, it should **not** be matched and the callback should **not** be applied to it. That's why I'm using regexes in the first place instead of string replacements.

Also, the reason I'm using capture groups this way is that I need the replacement process to be configurable. So I cannot hardcode something like "replace #1 and #2 but not #3". On a different input file, the positions might be different, or there might be more replacements needed, and only the regex used should change.

So if my input is `"15,LOWER,ME,NotThis,AND,ME,AGAIN"`, I want to be able to just change the regex, not the code and get the desired result. Basically, both $pattern and $data are variable.

Comment: You'll have `$match[1]` which is the first set of `()` in the pattern and `match[2]` which will be the second set of `()`so `print_r($match);` to see. And pattern is probably not right `^\d+,([^,]+),([^,]+),.*$` or something.

Comment: I'm aware that I have $match[n]. But that includes only the string of the matches, not their position in the input data. I cannot use that to run a replacement because I could have the same string in a different place where it should not be replaced.

Comment: Is it always just the second and third value you want to change casing on?

Comment: see clarification above. Sorry for not including it immediately.

Comment: So let's say you get a string that contains 10 words, then what? It's still very unclear how you want it to work. You say it needs to be "configurable" but for what and how? Should you configure what positions shouldn't be changed, or some specific words? What are the rules here? Now it's basically "help me write some code that does something in a specific, unknown pattern"

Comment: That does not clarify.  Give different examples of input and output that would be variable.

Comment: The idea is that I have this simple filter and I get handed data that needs to be modified. I don't want to change the code every time the data changes. I only want to write a new regex to match the new code.

Comment: You don't specify HOW you know it needs to be modified if not by position in the pattern.  Given `12,LOWERME,ANDME,ButNotMe` why not lower `ButNotMe`???  What is the logic to not lower that one but lower the other 2???

Comment: Also, where is `12,LOWERME,ANDME,ButNotMe` coming from?  Line in a file? Terminated by newline?  This is probably so much simpler.

Comment: It is an example. The logic is external. The data should be modified in the places indicated by the regex, but not in the other places. One use case is that the data contains price information which needs to be modified for different currencies. But it also contains non-price numerical data which, of course, needs to be left untouched. If I know how to tell where the prices are, I can express that in a regex. Only these matches should be transformed.

Comment: The data is actually coming from stdin, newline seperated. I'm handling it line-by-line. Just simplified it for this example.

Comment: Well, you simplified it to the point where no one can help :-( _places indicated by the regex_ are positional.

Comment: if you basically know what indexes to ignore, you can do this without regex. Just explode the string on `,`, iterate through the result, skip the positions you have "configured" and then do an implode again.

Comment: I'm using CSV data here for simplicity. My input data is **not** guaranteed to be comma-separated. If it were, I wouldn't need regex, that's true. I would've solved this in 10 minutes if it would only have to work for CSV data. :-)

Comment: Or you could simply add the separator as a part of the config and explode on that?

Comment: See my 2nd example above for why that won't work. CSV is still CSV if the separator isn't a comma. ;-)

Comment: Why don't you just replace captured groups (without complete match)?

Comment: @shudder that is exactly what I'm trying to do. Replace only the captured groups, not the rest.

Comment: Your second example simply has a spaces as separator instead of commas. So `$separator = ' '; explode($separator, $string);` should still separate the words, no? You keep saying that the data isn't in that format but all you show us it that format.

Comment: The 2nd example has two separators '-' and ' '.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This uses `preg_match()` and `PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE` to return the capture groups and the offset within the original string where it is found.  This then uses `substr_replace()` with each capture group to replace only the part of the string which is to be changed - this stops any chance of replacing similar text which you do not want to be changed...

```
function lowerParts (string $input, string $regex ) {
    preg_match($regex, $input, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    array_shift($matches);
    foreach ( $matches as $match )  {
        $input = substr_replace($input, strtolower($match[0]),
            $match[1], strlen($match[0]));
    }
    return $input;
}
echo lowerParts ("12,LOWERME,ANDME,ButNotMe", "/^\d+,(.*),(.*),.*$/");
```

gives...

```
12,lowerme,andme,ButNotMe
```

But also with

```
echo lowerParts ("12,LOWERME,ANDME,LOWERME", "/^\d+,(.*),(.*),.*$/");
```

it gives

```
12,lowerme,andme,LOWERME
```

Edit:

If the replacement data is of different lengths, then you would need to chop the string up into parts and replace each one.  The complication is that each change in length alters the relative position of the offsets, so this has to keep track of what this offset is.  This version also has a parameter which is the process you want to apply to the strings (this example just passes `"strtolower"`) ...

```
function processParts (string $input, string $regex, callable $process ) {
    preg_match($regex, $input, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    array_shift($matches);
    $offset = 0;
    foreach ( $matches as $match )  {
        $replacement = $process($match[0]);
        $input = substr($input, 0, $match[1]+$offset)
                 .$replacement.
                 substr($input, $match[1]+$offset+strlen($match[0]));
        $offset += strlen($replacement) - strlen($match[0]);
    }
    return $input;
}
echo processParts ("12,LOWERME,ANDME,LOWERME", "/^\d+,.*,(.*),(.*)$/", "strtolower");
```

Comment: This works as long as the replacement has the same length as the original. Unfortunately in my use case that isn't always true. My apologies that this was not clear in the question.

Comment: Added a replacement, it just chops the string into parts, also allows you to pass a function to process the strings with.

Comment: Interesting approach. Might be faster than Nick's answer because it needs fewer regex computations.

Comment: @Tom First example will work if you loop in reverse order (`foreach (array_reverse($matches) ...) {}`) - replacement won't affect other offests.

Comment: @NigelRen you should just update your answer with the `array_reverse` idea. Seems a reasonable trade...

Answer (score 1):

This will work:

```
function replaceGroups(string $pattern, string $string, callable $callback)
{
    preg_match($pattern, $string, $matches, PREG_OFFSET_CAPTURE);
    array_shift($matches);

    foreach (array_reverse($matches) as $match) {
        $string = substr_replace($string, $callback($match[0]), $match[1], mb_strlen($match[0]));
    }

    return $string;
}

echo replaceGroups("/^\d+-\d+-(.*) .* (.*)$/", "13-007-THISLOWER ThisNot THISAGAIN", 'strtolower');
```

Comment: If you are going to post this a separate answer, I would at least appreciate some form of attribution of where most of the code comes from. (Besides the only explanation being *This will work* provides very little for any future reader)